# RestSharp PUT request changes nothing

Tags: c#, restsharp, rest

I am trying to change a property of a purchase order within our ERP, but when I do a PUT request with Restsharp, the code seems to run fine, but it doesn't actually do anything. I get no error codes, so I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.

```
string url = "http://192.16.175.97:888/";
        var client2 = new RestClient(url);
        client2.Timeout = -1;
        var request2 = new RestRequest("api/PurchaseOrder?Ordernumber=50007996", Method.PUT);
        request2.AddHeader("X-ApiKey", apikey);
        request2.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request2.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request2.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request2.AddJsonBody(putbodyupdated);
        client2.Execute(request2);
```

I am just asking if something is wrong with my C# code, otherwise I will look further in my url's or JSON.

I've run multiple GET requests, which seems to work fine.

Maybe it's useful to share my whole code:

```
 var client = new RestClient("http://192.16.175.97:888/");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest("api/PurchaseOrder?Ordernumber=50007996", Method.GET);
        string apikey = "xxxx";
        
        request.AddHeader("X-ApiKey", apikey);
        
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
         IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        string putbody = response.Content;

        Console.WriteLine(putbody);

        // Convert the JSON string to a JObject:
        JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(putbody) as JObject;
        // Select a nested property using a single string:
        JToken 
        jToken = jObject.SelectToken("Header.Description");
        jToken.Replace("test2");
        // Convert the JObject back to a string:
        string putbodyupdated = jObject.ToString();



        Console.WriteLine(putbodyupdated);


        string url = "http://192.16.175.97:888/";
        var client2 = new RestClient(url);
        client2.Timeout = -1;
        var request2 = new RestRequest("api/PurchaseOrder?Ordernumber=50007996", Method.PUT);
        request2.AddHeader("X-ApiKey", apikey);
        request2.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request2.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request2.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request2.AddJsonBody(putbodyupdated);
        var response2 =  client2.Execute(request2);

        Console.WriteLine(response2.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine(response2.Content);
        Console.WriteLine(response2.StatusDescription);
```

Comment: What's the response status code?  Does it return a 20x?

Comment: All i get is this: C:\Users\Online\source\repos\xxx\VER.exe (process 3232) exited with code 0.

Comment: Change to `var response = client2.Execute(request2);` and check the actual response, is it a HTTP 200 (OK) or has it failed? response has a `StatusCode` `Content` and other useful properties.

Comment: Hi Ryan, statuscode returns "OK". Content returns "true"

Comment: It appears that the API has said everything is OK.  If nothing is happening on the server, then it's the servers fault, not yours.

Comment: Check if "http://192.16.175.97:888/api/PurchaseOrder?Ordernumber=50007996" - This endpoint is a PUT endpoint. If this is a GET endpoint you can't hit it with a PUT request

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The right endpoint would be api/PurchaseOrder?addOnly={addOnly}&instructionOnly={instructionOnly} . How would I specify the right purchase order with this. Does is get that from the body? That's the only other place where this is specified.

Comment: Alright, I checked that out and it appears to call to the right purchase order, but still nothing happens.